# Trace/BPT trap: 5 running grails 2.1.0 app - Trace/BPT trap: 5

Tags: grails

I upgraded an app from 2.0.0M2 to 2.1.0 but when I try to run it I got this error:

```
Note: /Volumes/Info/proyectos-grails/vincoorbis/Member-2.1.0/member/src/groovy/com/vincoorbis/aeromexico/clubpremier/member/WSCredentialsException.j va uses or overrides a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

| Creating SSL Certificate...

Created SSL Certificate.

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Here is the log:

```
Process:         java [10418]
Path:            /usr/bin/java
Identifier:      com.apple.javajdk16.cmd
Version:         1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [8980]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-09-03 12:16:47.579 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8 (12A269)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          1320567 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           13
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  111302 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   12
Anonymous UUID:                      92ED5BE2-E51C-418A-A60B-388303A36546

Crashed Thread:  5  Java: GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Java information:
 Exception type: Internal Error (/SourceCache/JavaJDK16/JavaJDK16-424/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/javaCalls.cpp, line 62)

#  guarantee(thread->is_Java_thread()) failed: crucial check - the VM thread cannot and must not escape to Java code
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.8-b03-424 mixed mode macosx-amd64)

Current thread (7fd2fb801800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 10c32d000,10c42d000] [id=205705216]
Stack: [10c32d000,10c42d000]
JavaThread 7fd2fe8d5800 (nid = 4540796928) was being processed
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.springsource.loaded.Utils.loadBytesFromStream(Ljava/io/InputStream;)[B+12
j  com.springsource.loaded.Utils.loadClassAsBytes2(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)[B+39
J  com.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.getDescriptorFor(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;
J  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.computeFieldsRequiringAccessors()V
j  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.getTypeDescriptor()Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;+12
J  com.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.getDescriptorFor(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;
J  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.computeFieldsRequiringAccessors()V
j  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.getTypeDescriptor()Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;+12
J  com.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.getDescriptorFor(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;
J  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.computeFieldsRequiringAccessors()V
j  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.getTypeDescriptor()Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;+12
J  com.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.getDescriptorFor(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;
J  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.findTypeDescriptor(Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeRegistry;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;
J  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.computeCatchers()V
j  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor$ExtractionVisitor.getTypeDescriptor()Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;+8
j  com.springsource.loaded.TypeDescriptorExtractor.extract([BZ)Lcom/springsource/loaded/TypeDescriptor;+29
j  com.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.addType(Ljava/lang/String;[B)Lcom/springsource/loaded/ReloadableType;+50
J  com.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;[B)[B
J  sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;[B)[B
j  sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;[BZ)[B+34
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+32
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class;+9
j  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.define(Ljava/lang/String;[B)Ljava/lang/Class;+26
j  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run()Ljava/lang/Class;+12
j  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.defineClassAndGetConstructor(Ljava/lang/String;[B)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+10
j  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.compileStaticMethod(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/reflection/CachedMethod;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+43
j  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createStaticMetaMethodSite(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;Lgroovy/lang/MetaClassImpl;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;+30
j  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.createStaticMetaMethodSite(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;Lgroovy/lang/MetaClassImpl;Lgroovy/lang/MetaMethod;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;+56
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createStaticSite(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;+36
j  groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.createStaticSite(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;+20
j  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;+18
j  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;+26
j  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+3
j  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+3
j  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5
j  BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6360
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.Closure.call([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.Closure.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Lgrails/util/Environment;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Lgrails/util/Environment$EnvironmentBlockEvaluator;+16
j  grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Lgrails/util/Environment;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V+23
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication;Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V+113
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;+131
j  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContextEvent;)V+28
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart()Z+530
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal()V+1187
j  org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start()V+210
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call()Ljava/lang/Void;+4
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun()V+30
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+4
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+59
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+28
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing the springloaded java agent with a snapshot version from http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/com/springsource/springloaded/springloaded-core/

Download http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/com/springsource/springloaded/springloaded-core/1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/springloaded-core-1.1.1.BUILD-20120821.173635-2.jar and place it on top the springloaded version that comes with Grails 2.1.0 , thats
grails-2.1.0/lib/com.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.0.6.jar

for example:

```
wget http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/com/springsource/springloaded/springloaded-core/1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/springloaded-core-1.1.1.BUILD-20120821.173635-2.jar
mv springloaded-core-1.1.1.BUILD-20120821.173635-2.jar $GRAILS_HOME/lib/com.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.0.6.jar
```

There are a few users that reported the same problem on the mailing list:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=1312388&query=%22crucial+check%22&days=0

There are jira issues such as http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9019 / https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2851 (about java.lang.ClassCircularityError) that seem to be fixed in the Springloaded 1.1.1 snapshot.

Please re-test with the snapshot and report a jira issue with steps to reproduce the problem. Do you have a chance to test the same application on Linux or Windows?

You can also remove the ~/.grails/.slcache directory to make sure Springloaded agent has a clean start.

Comment: An interesting suggestion on JRebel forum after a similar crash to find out a possible error message: "Could you please remove -noverify/-Xverify:none from the JVM command line and see what error comes then." (http://zeroturnaround.com/forum/topic.php?id=627) You would have to edit $GRAILS_HOME/bin/startGrails and temporarily remove "-noverify" from the AGENT_STRING line to see if that gives any better error message.

Comment: To enable Springloaded logging: edit the line SPRINGLOADED_PARAMS="profile=grails" in startGrails and make it SPRINGLOADED_PARAMS="logging=true;verbose=true;profile=grails" . You should be able to see what class Springloaded is handling when it crashes.

Comment: Logging level might have to be adjusted to get the logging messages from com.springsource.loaded loggers (it's using JUL logging).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to erase the `~/.grails` and `yourproject/target` directories and then try again.

Comment: Well, then you can wait an answer from people that really know it from inside like @BurtBeckwith